# Creating Network Drive

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-to-vb.net

I need to help in following requirement.

I want to create a Desktop application which creates the network drive on my local machine. When user clicks on the network drive the it ask for username and password. Username and password will check with the database by web service.

The document in the network will filter by permission which is stored in the database. For example on the server all the document store in single folder and permission of different user store in the database. User1 can read 5 documents and User2 can read the 10 documents. So the access of different file is according to user permission.

Is the above is possible. Please suggest me some links related to this.

Please suggest me what I need to study.
Thanks & Regards
Jelly

Comment: Do you mean a mapped drive?

Comment: There is a product from Microsoft which gives you what you want and more flexibility in doing policy driven documents. the product name is Active directory Rights Management system. with this you dont need to create a virtual drive check this http://www.sghaida.com/ad-rms-protecting-a-document-programmatically/

Answer (score 0):

the part which is related to asking for user and password its easy . you can hook into CreateFileW and CreateFileA using [easyhook](http://easyhook.codeplex.com) library check this [link](http://www.sghaida.com/transparent-encryption-layer-using-easyhook/) as for creating virtual drive you can do it using this [library](http://dokan-dev.net/en/). i hope that helped

Comment: Thanks for reply but please clarify one point.
Can we filter the document according to the database? WE store the entire document in same location. The information regarding which user access which document is stored in the database. When we create network drive for user then I have to show only that documents which he has access.
When user drag drops any document in the network drive then we have save entry in the database. 
I just want to know is this possible using c# or not. I have not done this kind of work earlier.

Comment: sure it could be done, but the problem there is no straightforward way to do it you need to have a virtual drive as a component(dokan Lib) provide you with all the underlying methods to create a custom file system. so yes it could be implemented but it needs a lot of code and some system hooking for file manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Database Table for permission sets: For an example

create table FilePermission
(
Id_User Integer,
pwd varchar(100),
FileName Varchar(1000)
ReadRights char(1),
Writable char(1),
Editable char(1)
)

Create a windows service, which will do the following things :
1.  Fetch the values from FilePermission table using id_user and FileName 
2.  If suppose it has read only access (ReadRights == 1) then start the Window application through Process exe.

I Hope it will help to go ahead.